# Very long and large tables

Tags: tables, scaling, scalebox

as you might guess from the title I have a problem including two very big tables in my document.
The first table is very long but short (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Data check}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{cb}
\usepackage{pdflscape,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry} % just not to bother with the table width

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.27}{
\begin{tabular}{||l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c||} \hline
\textbf{Molecule} & \textbf{ALGERIA} & \textbf{AUSTRALIA} & \textbf{AUSTRIA} & \textbf{BELGIUM} & \textbf{BULGARIA} & \textbf{CANADA} & \textbf{CENTRAL AMERICA} & \textbf{CHINA} & \textbf{COLOMBIA} & \textbf{CROATIA} & \textbf{CZECH REP.} & \textbf{DENMARK} & \textbf{EGYPT} & \textbf{FINLAND} & \textbf{FRANCE} & \textbf{GERMANY} & \textbf{GREECE} & \textbf{HUNGARY} & \textbf{INDIA} & \textbf{IRELAND} & \textbf{ITALY} & \textbf{JAPAN} & \textbf{NETHERLANDS} & \textbf{POLAND} & \textbf{PORTUGAL} & \textbf{ROMANIA} & \textbf{RUSSIA} & \textbf{SERBIA} & \textbf{SLOVAKIA} & \textbf{SLOVENIA} & \textbf{SPAIN} & \textbf{SWEDEN} & \textbf{TURKEY} & \textbf{UK} & \textbf{USA} \\ \hline
ACETYLCYSTEINE & 0.0280 & -0.57** & -0.59** & -0.58** & -0.33** & -0.57** & -0.64** & -0.160 & -0.110 & -0.41** & -0.53** & -0.60** & 0.0140 & -0.56** & -0.57** & -0.59** & -0.43** & -0.46** & 0.402 & -0.64** & -0.54** & -0.53** & -0.60** & -0.46** & -0.48** & -0.43** & -0.41** & -0.22** & -0.46** & -0.51** & -0.52** & -0.58** & -0.41** & -0.56** & -0.62** \\
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID & -0.08** & 0.183 & 0.224 & 0.197 & -0.0100 & 0.177 & 0.398 & -0.0600 & -0.07** & 0.0270 & 0.124 & 0.235 & -0.08** & 0.175 & 0.181 & 0.230 & 0.0370 & 0.0610 & -0.07** & 0.402 & 0.138 & 0.124 & 0.252 & 0.0630 & 0.0750 & 0.0380 & 0.0240 & -0.0500 & 0.0590 & 0.107 & 0.120 & 0.205 & 0.0260 & 0.164 & 0.300 \\
ACICLOVIR & -0.24** & -0.15** & -0.16** & -0.15** & -0.15** & -0.15** & -0.220 & -0.19** & -0.20** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.16** & -0.24** & -0.15** & -0.15** & -0.16** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.380 & -0.220 & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.17** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.17** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.15** & -0.14** & -0.15** & -0.18** \\
ALLOPURINOL & 0.495 & -0.33** & -0.23** & -0.30** & -0.35** & -0.34** & 0.288** & -0.0100 & 0.103 & -0.44** & -0.42** & -0.21** & 0.454 & -0.34** & -0.33** & -0.22** & -0.45** & -0.46** & 1.713** & 0.300** & -0.40** & -0.42** & -0.16** & -0.46** & -0.46** & -0.45** & -0.44** & -0.150 & -0.46** & -0.44** & -0.43** & -0.28** & -0.44** & -0.36** & -0.03** \\
AMLODIPINE & -0.590 & 0.191 & 0.358 & 0.247 & -0.51** & 0.167 & 1.093 & -0.62** & -0.63** & -0.38** & -0.0400 & 0.400 & -0.600 & 0.157 & 0.181 & 0.381 & -0.350 & -0.270 & -0.28** & 1.108 & 0.0120 & -0.0400 & 0.471 & -0.260 & -0.220 & -0.350 & -0.39** & -0.60** & -0.280 & -0.100 & -0.0500 & 0.280 & -0.39** & 0.113 & 0.672 \\
BETAMETHASONE & 0.0940 & -0.16** & -0.04** & -0.12** & -0.44** & -0.18** & 0.579** & -0.25** & -0.17** & -0.45** & -0.31** & -0.01** & 0.0650 & -0.19** & -0.17** & -0.02** & -0.45** & -0.42** & 1.025** & 0.592** & -0.28** & -0.31** & 0.043** & -0.42** & -0.40** & -0.45** & -0.45** & -0.34** & -0.43** & -0.35** & -0.32** & -0.10** & -0.45** & -0.22** & 0.207** \\
BISOPROLOL & -1.46** & -0.77** & -0.78** & -0.77** & -0.94** & -0.77** & -0.90** & -1.17** & -1.24** & -0.85** & -0.78** & -0.79** & -1.44** & -0.77** & -0.77** & -0.78** & -0.84** & -0.81** & -2.09** & -0.90** & -0.77** & -0.78** & -0.79** & -0.81** & -0.80** & -0.84** & -0.86** & -1.08** & -0.82** & -0.78** & -0.78** & -0.78** & -0.86** & -0.77** & -0.82** \\
BUDESONIDE & -0.67** & -0.22** & -0.0400 & -0.16** & -0.87** & -0.25** & 0.773 & -0.86** & -0.83** & -0.78** & -0.46** & 0 & -0.69** & -0.26** & -0.23** & -0.0200 & -0.75** & -0.68** & -0.01** & 0.791 & -0.41** & -0.46** & 0.0730 & -0.68** & -0.63** & -0.75** & -0.79** & -0.88** & -0.69** & -0.52** & -0.48** & -0.13** & -0.78** & -0.30** & 0.295 \\
CARBAMAZEPINE & -0.74** & -0.0600 & 0.0480 & -0.0200 & -0.57** & -0.0700 & 0.518 & -0.69** & -0.71** & -0.47** & -0.21** & 0.0760 & -0.74** & -0.0800 & -0.0600 & 0.0630 & -0.44** & -0.38** & -0.66** & 0.528 & -0.18** & -0.21** & 0.122 & -0.37** & -0.34** & -0.44** & -0.47** & -0.66** & -0.38** & -0.26** & -0.22** & 0 & -0.47** & -0.11** & 0.251 \\
CIPROFLOXACIN & 0.0420 & 0.137 & 0.106 & 0.127 & 0.200** & 0.142 & -0.0500 & 0.144** & 0.121 & 0.207 & 0.175 & 0.0970 & 0.0510 & 0.143 & 0.139 & 0.101 & 0.207 & 0.202 & -0.210 & -0.0600 & 0.167 & 0.175 & 0.0830 & 0.201 & 0.197 & 0.206 & 0.207** & 0.169** & 0.202 & 0.184 & 0.177 & 0.121 & 0.207 & 0.151 & 0.0400 \\
CLINDAMYCIN & -0.62** & -0.13** & -0.11** & -0.12** & -0.31** & -0.13** & -0.100 & -0.46** & -0.50** & -0.24** & -0.16** & -0.11** & -0.61** & -0.13** & -0.13** & -0.11** & -0.23** & -0.21** & -0.96** & -0.100 & -0.15** & -0.16** & -0.11** & -0.21** & -0.19** & -0.23** & -0.25** & -0.40** & -0.21** & -0.17** & -0.16** & -0.12** & -0.25** & -0.14** & -0.100 \\
DEXAMETHASONE & 0.130 & 0.0320 & 0.0490 & 0.0370 & 0.0130 & 0.0300 & 0.139 & 0.0580 & 0.0750 & 0.00300 & 0.0130 & -1.78** & 0.124 & 0.0290 & 0.0310 & -1.80** & 0.00200 & 0.00300 & 0.309 & 0.142 & 0.0170 & 0.0130 & 0.0610 & 0.00300 & 0.00400 & 0.00200 & 0.00300 & 0.0390 & 0.00300 & 0.00900 & 0.0120 & 0.0410 & 0.00300 & 0.0250 & -0.74** \\
DICLOFENAC & 0.885 & -0.180 & -0.170 & -0.180 & 0.110 & -0.180 & -0.03** & 0.451 & 0.558 & -0.02** & -0.160 & -0.170 & 0.852 & -0.180 & -0.180 & -0.170 & -0.04** & -0.0900 & 1.812 & -0.03** & -0.170 & -0.160 & -0.160 & -0.0900 & -0.110 & -0.05** & -0.01** & 0.321 & -0.0900 & -0.150 & -0.160 & -0.180 & -0.02** & -0.170 & -0.13** \\
FINASTERIDE & -0.390 & -0.63** & -0.52** & -0.60** & -0.86** & -0.64** & 0.00300 & -0.70** & -0.63** & -0.87** & -0.76** & -0.50** & -0.42** & -0.65** & -0.64** & -0.51** & -0.87** & -0.85** & 0.411 & 0.0150 & -0.73** & -0.76** & -0.45** & -0.85** & -0.83** & -0.87** & -0.87** & -0.77** & -0.85** & -0.79** & -0.76** & -0.57** & -0.87** & -0.67** & -0.310 \\
FLUCONAZOLE & 0.0830 & -0.13** & 0.0120 & -0.0800 & -0.50** & -0.15** & 0.770** & -0.31** & -0.220 & -0.51** & -0.32** & 0.097** & 0.0490 & -0.16** & -0.14** & 0.0340 & -0.50** & -0.46** & 1.143** & 0.786** & -0.28** & -0.32** & 0.120 & -0.46** & -0.44** & -0.50** & -0.51** & -0.40** & -0.47** & -0.36** & -0.33** & -0.0500 & -0.51** & -0.20** & 0.321 \\
FUROSEMIDE & -0.730 & 0.199 & 0.221 & 0.207 & -0.130 & 0.194 & 0.236 & -0.410 & -0.49** & -0.0100 & 0.147 & 0.225 & -0.710 & 0.193 & 0.197 & 0.223 & 0.00900 & 0.0580 & -1.380 & 0.235 & 0.162 & 0.147 & 0.231 & 0.0610 & 0.0820 & 0.0120 & -0.0200 & -0.310 & 0.0540 & 0.128 & 0.143 & 0.212 & -0.0100 & 0.184 & 0.241 \\
IBUPROFEN & 0.326 & -0.100 & -0.0700 & -0.0900 & -0.0500 & -0.100 & 0.101** & 0.101 & 0.155 & -0.10** & -0.120 & -0.0600 & 0.308 & -0.100 & -0.100 & -0.0700 & -0.11** & -0.12** & 0.842 & 0.105** & -0.120 & -0.120 & -0.05** & -0.12** & -0.12** & -0.11** & -0.10** & 0.0380 & -0.12** & -0.120 & -0.120 & -0.0800 & -0.10** & -0.110 & -0.00** \\
KETOCONAZOLE & -0.0800 & -0.21** & -0.23** & -0.22** & -0.13** & -0.21** & -0.28** & -0.100 & -0.0900 & -0.15** & -0.19** & -0.23** & -0.0800 & -0.21** & -0.21** & -0.23** & -0.15** & -0.16** & -0.0500 & -0.29** & -0.20** & -0.19** & -0.24** & -0.17** & -0.17** & -0.16** & -0.15** & -0.110 & -0.16** & -0.18** & -0.19** & -0.22** & -0.15** & -0.20** & -0.25** \\
LACTULOSE & -2.73** & -0.15** & -0.03** & -0.12** & -1.09** & -0.16** & -0.0200 & -1.85** & -2.07** & -0.75** & -0.30** & -0.0700 & -2.67** & -0.17** & -0.15** & -0.08** & -0.69** & -0.55** & -4.50** & -0.0200 & -0.26** & -0.30** & -0.0500 & -0.54** & -0.48** & -0.68** & -0.77** & -1.57** & -0.56** & -0.35** & -0.31** & -0.11** & -0.76** & -0.19** & -0.0200 \\
LEVOTHYROXINE SODIUM & 0.0900 & 0.00200 & 0.0130 & 0.00600 & 0 & 0.00100 & 0.0720 & 0.0340 & 0.0480 & -0.0100 & 0.155** & 0.0150 & 0.0860 & 0 & 0.00200 & 0.0140 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & 0.223 & 0.0730 & 0 & 0 & 0.0200 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & 0.0190 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & 0 & 0.00800 & -0.0100 & 0 & 0.0360 \\
LORATADINE & -1.68** & 0.284 & 0.00700 & 0.195 & 0.508** & 0.320 & -1.54** & -0.34** & -0.650 & 0.719 & 0.591 & -0.0600 & -1.58** & 0.336 & 0.300 & -0.0300 & 0.736 & 0.745 & -4.94** & -1.57** & 0.530 & 0.591 & -0.200 & 0.744 & 0.729 & 0.737 & 0.710 & 0.013** & 0.746 & 0.652 & 0.606 & 0.141 & 0.714 & 0.398 & -0.600 \\
MESALAZINE & 0.997 & -0.490 & -0.520 & -0.500 & 0.0280 & -0.480 & -0.520 & 0.471 & 0.604 & -0.160 & -0.410 & -0.520 & 0.957 & -0.480 & -0.480 & -0.520 & -0.200 & -0.270 & 2.064 & -0.510 & -0.430 & -0.410 & -0.530 & -0.280 & -0.31** & -0.200 & -0.150 & 0.307 & -0.270 & -0.380 & -0.400 & -0.500 & -0.160 & -0.470 & -0.540 \\
METHYLPREDNISOLONE & -0.260 & -0.44** & -0.35** & -0.41** & -0.65** & -0.45** & 0.106 & -0.52** & -0.46** & -0.65** & -0.55** & -0.32** & -0.280 & -0.45** & -0.44** & -0.33** & -0.65** & -0.63** & 0.402 & 0.116 & -0.52** & -0.55** & -0.28** & -0.63** & -0.62** & -0.65** & -0.66** & -0.58** & -0.63** & -0.57** & -0.55** & -0.39** & -0.65** & -0.48** & -0.160 \\
METOPROLOL & 1.677 & -0.340 & -0.410 & -0.370 & 0.437** & -0.330 & -0.54** & 1.017 & 1.185 & 0.163** & -0.200 & -0.420 & 1.628 & -0.320 & -0.340 & -0.420 & 0.115** & 0.004** & 2.972 & -0.54** & -0.240 & -0.200 & -0.440 & -0.00** & -0.05** & 0.109** & 0.181** & 0.806 & 0.012** & -0.16** & -0.190 & -0.380 & 0.172** & -0.300 & -0.490 \\
METRONIDAZOLE & 0.0120 & 0.00400 & 0.0130 & 0.00700 & -0.0200 & 0.00200 & 0.0590 & -0.0100 & 0 & -0.0100 & 0 & 0.015** & 0.0100 & 0.00200 & 0.00300 & 0.0140 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & 0.0720 & 0.0600 & 0 & 0 & 0.0200 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & -0.0100 & 0 & 0.00800 & -0.0100 & 3.586 & 0.0320 \\
OMEPRAZOLE & -0.76** & -0.0200 & 0.104 & 0.0190 & -0.61** & -0.0400 & 0.658 & -0.73** & -0.75** & -0.49** & -0.20** & 0.136 & -0.76** & -0.0500 & -0.0300 & 0.121 & -0.46** & -0.39** & -0.64** & 0.670 & -0.160 & -0.20** & 0.190 & -0.39** & -0.35** & -0.46** & -0.50** & -0.70** & -0.40** & -0.25** & -0.21** & 0.0440 & -0.49** & -0.0800 & 0.343 \\
PARACETAMOL & -0.170 & -0.26** & -0.27** & -0.26** & -0.18** & -0.25** & -0.36** & -0.16** & -0.16** & -0.19** & -0.23** & -0.28** & -0.170 & -0.25** & -0.25** & -0.28** & -0.19** & -0.20** & -0.210 & -0.36** & -0.24** & -0.23** & -0.29** & -0.20** & -0.21** & -0.19** & -0.19** & -0.17** & -0.20** & -0.22** & -0.23** & -0.27** & -0.19** & -0.25** & -0.31** \\
RANITIDINE & -0.350 & 0.253 & 0.304 & 0.270 & -0.0700 & 0.245 & 0.495 & -0.210 & -0.25** & 0.0160 & 0.172 & 0.316 & -0.340 & 0.242 & 0.249 & 0.311 & 0.0330 & 0.0750 & -0.550 & 0.498 & 0.192 & 0.172 & 0.337 & 0.0780 & 0.0990 & 0.0350 & 0.00900 & -0.160 & 0.0720 & 0.148 & 0.166 & 0.281 & 0.0130 & 0.227 & 0.391 \\
RISPERIDONE & 0.188 & -0.0400 & 0.0330 & -0.0100 & -0.19** & -0.05** & 0.423** & -0.0500 & 0 & -0.20** & -0.13** & 0.0530 & 0.168 & -0.05** & -0.0400 & 0.0430 & -0.20** & -0.19** & 0.818** & 0.431** & -0.11** & -0.13** & 0.0870 & -0.19** & -0.18** & -0.20** & -0.20** & -0.11** & -0.19** & -0.15** & -0.13** & 0 & -0.20** & -0.07** & 0.190** \\
SALBUTAMOL & 0.117** & 0.192 & 0.219** & 0.201 & 0.092** & 0.188 & 0.345 & 0.091** & 0.095** & 0.106** & 0.155 & 0.226 & 0.114** & 0.186 & 0.190 & 0.381** & 0.110** & 0.121** & 0.212** & 0.347 & 0.163 & 0.155 & 0.238 & 0.122** & 0.128** & 0.110** & 0.104** & 0.088** & 0.120** & 0.146 & 0.153 & 0.206 & 0.105** & 0.179 & 0.272 \\
SIMVASTATIN & 1.193 & -0.06** & -0.140 & -0.09** & 0.541** & -0.05** & -0.430 & 0.868 & 0.955 & 0.364** & 0.072** & -0.160 & 1.170 & -0.04** & -0.06** & -0.160 & 0.330** & 0.250** & 1.757 & -0.430 & 0.037** & 0.072** & -0.200 & 0.243** & 0.205** & 0.326** & 0.377** & 0.755 & 0.256** & 0.115** & 0.082** & -0.11** & 0.370** & -0.02** & -0.280 \\
 TESTOSTERONE & 0.199 & -1.80** & -1.790 & -1.80** & -1.27** & -1.80** & -1.500 & -0.62** & -0.42** & -1.53** & -1.78** & -1.780 & 0.135 & -1.80** & -1.80** & -1.780 & -1.57** & -1.66** & 1.980 & -1.490 & -1.79** & -1.78** & -1.760 & -1.66** & -1.70** & -1.58** & -1.51** & -0.87** & -1.65** & -1.76** & -1.77** & -1.80** & -1.52** & -1.80** & -1.700 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
    \caption{Table of own elasticities by country}
    \label{own_tab}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

The problem with the latter table is that being too long, even if I am doing a sidewaytable, I have to scale it to 0.27, which makes it very difficult to read it. I don't know if there are other solutions to make it larger but I can stay with that in case there are not.

The real problem is with another table (which for sake of space I cannot include here) having the same exact number of columns as the above table but many many rows more, i.e. 992. For the sake of simplicity imagine the above table but with 900 rows rather than 32. Now my question is: can I include the whole table in the document (even if scaled)? Is there a way to do that? Actually, my attempt failed as showed below in thee picture (I am doing a sidewaystable and a scalebox there as well):

[image]

EDIT: of course also including the table on multiple pages is good.

Comment: See [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Comment: Regarding the table itself: You could save some space by abbreviating the country names, for example using the ISO 3166-1 codes in order to avoid wasted space due to overly wide column headers. You probably also want to split the table into at least three parts, showing 12 country columns in each part. Slightly reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` could also help to save some more space. Lastly, you may also want to use lower case letters for the molecule names instead of all caps in order to save even more horizontal space.

Comment: Unrelated to the table but you may want to start by cleaing up your preamble. You currently load multiple packages more than once, `booktabs` even 4 times. Also, you use incompatible packages (`subcaption` and `subfig` can't be used in the same document.) resulting in a document that currently isn't compilable.

Comment: The table(s)  must be cut into pieces to fit in pages, the strategy will depend on the objective of the table:
(1) Document the content, it is not necessary for the reader. Or

(2) It should be read horizontally to compare a group of compounds between different countries.  Or

(3) to be read vertically showing the full list of compounds for a group of countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is far to huge that can be fit on one A$ page in readable form (even with A3 page you can't satisfactory solve this). You need to splet table in two parts (if it is insert in document in landscape orientation) or three parts an try to fit it in portrait orientation.

As example see possible solution when is considered aforementioned the first case and first five rows of table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
    \scriptsize
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{COLOMBIA}
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.3{**},
             round-mode=places,
             round-precision = 3}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt,
             colsep  = 1pt,
             colspec = {@{} X[2.3,l] *{17}{X[c, si]}@{}},
             row{1}  = {cmd=\rotcell, font=\bfseries, c}, % <----
             measure = vbox,
            }
Molecule
    & {{{ALGERIA}}}         & {{{AUSTRALIA}}}       & {{{AUSTRIA}}}
    & {{{BELGIUM}}}         & {{{BULGARIA}}}        & {{{CANADA}}}
    & {{{CENTRAL AMERICA}}} & {{{CHINA}}}           & {{{COLOMBIA}}}
    & {{{CROATIA}}}         & {{{CZECH REPUBLIC}}}  & {{{DENMARK}}}
    & {{{EGYPT}}}           & {{{FINLAND}}}         & {{{FRANCE}}}
    & {{{GERMANY}}}         & {{{GREECE}}}      \\      
ACETYLCYSTEINE 
    & 0.0280  & -0.57** & -0.59**  & -0.58** & -0.33** & -0.57** & -0.64** 
    & -0.160  & -0.110  & -0.41**  & -0.53** & -0.60** & 0.0140  & -0.56** 
    & -0.57** & -0.59** & -0.43** \\
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID 
    & -0.08** & 0.183   & 0.224   & 0.197    & -0.0100 & 0.177   & 0.398 
    & -0.0600 & -0.07** & 0.0270  & 0.124    & 0.235   & -0.08** & 0.175 
    & 0.181   & 0.230   & 0.0370  \\
ACICLOVIR 
    & -0.24** & -0.15** & -0.16** & -0.15** & -0.15** & -0.15** & -0.220 
    & -0.19** & -0.20** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.16** & -0.24** & -0.15** 
    & -0.15** & -0.16** & -0.14** \\
ALLOPURINOL 
    & 0.495   & -0.33** & -0.23** & -0.30** & -0.35** & -0.34** & 0.288** 
    & -0.0100 & 0.103   & -0.44** & -0.42** & -0.21** & 0.454   & -0.34** 
    & -0.33** & -0.22** & -0.45** \\
AMLODIPINE 
    & -0.590  & 0.191   & 0.358   & 0.247   & -0.51** & 0.167   & 1.093 
    & -0.62** & -0.63** & -0.38** & -0.0400 & 0.400   & -0.600  & 0.157 
    & 0.181   & 0.381   & -0.350  \\
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Table of own elasticities by country (first part)}
    \label{own_tab-1}
    \end{sidewaystable}

    \begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
    \ContinuedFloat
    \scriptsize
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{NETHERLAND }
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.3{**},
             round-mode=places,
             round-precision = 3}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt,
             colsep  = 1pt,
             colspec = {@{} X[2.3,l] *{18}{X[c, si]}@{}},
             row{1}  = {cmd=\rotcell, font=\bfseries, c}, % <----
             measure = vbox,
            }
Molecule
    & {{{HUNGARY}}}
    & {{{INDIA}}}             & {{{IRELAND}}}     & {{{ITALY}}}
    & {{{JAPAN}}}             & {{{NETHERLAND}}}  & {{{POLAND}}}
    & {{{PORTUGAL}}}          & {{{ROMANIA}}}     & {{{RUSSIA}}}
    & {{{SERBIA}}}            & {{{SLOVAKIA}}}    & {{{SLOVENIA}}}
    & {{{SPAIN}}}             & {{{SWEDEN}}}      & {{{TURKEY}}}
    & {{{UK}}}                & {{{USA}}}       \\

ACETYLCYSTEINE
    & -0.46** & 0.402   & -0.64** & -0.54** & -0.53** & -0.60** & -0.46** 
    & -0.48** & -0.43** & -0.41** & -0.22** & -0.46** & -0.51** & -0.52** 
    & -0.58** & -0.41** & -0.56** & -0.62**     \\
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID
    & 0.0610  & -0.07** & 0.402   & 0.138   & 0.124   & 0.252   & 0.0630 
    & 0.0750  & 0.0380  & 0.0240  & -0.0500 & 0.0590  & 0.107   & 0.120 
    & 0.205   & 0.0260  & 0.164   & 0.300       \\
ACICLOVIR
    & -0.14** & -0.380  & -0.220  & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.17** & -0.14** 
    & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.17** & -0.14** & -0.14** & -0.14** 
    & -0.15** & -0.14** & -0.15** & -0.18**     \\
ALLOPURINOL
    & -0.46** & 1.713** & 0.300** & -0.40** & -0.42** & -0.16** & -0.46** 
    & -0.46** & -0.45** & -0.44** & -0.150  & -0.46** & -0.44** & -0.43** 
    & -0.28** & -0.44** & -0.36** & -0.03**     \\
AMLODIPINE
    & -0.270  & -0.28** & 1.108   & 0.0120  & -0.0400 & 0.471   & -0.260  
    & -0.220  & -0.350  & -0.39** & -0.60** & -0.280  & -0.100  & -0.0500 
    & 0.280   & -0.39** & 0.113   & 0.672       \\
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Table of own elasticities by country (second part)}
    \label{own_tab}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: when I apply yourr solution an error appears saying "tabularray.sty" not found

Comment: @NutarelliFederico, that means that you not have installed it.  Install it as you install other packages.